# React - Trying to change color of text for the active link

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to change the color of the text based on the page in my navbar that the user is currently on. I'm not sure if its an issue with my css selectors or if it is something else, but the text won't change?

my navbar..

```
function NavBar() {


  return (
    <>



      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">BadBank</a>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className={`nav-item ${location.pathname === '/home/' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
              <a className="nav-link" href="#/home/" title="Home" >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li className={`nav-item ${location.pathname === '/createaccount/' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
              <a className="nav-link" href="#/createaccount/" title="Create a new account" >Create Account</a>
            </li>
            <li className={`nav-item ${location.pathname === '/deposit/' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
              <a className="nav-link" href="#/deposit/" title="Deposit money" >Deposit</a>
            </li>
            <li className={`nav-item ${location.pathname === '/withdraw/' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
              <a className="nav-link" href="#/withdraw/" title="Withdraw money" >Withdraw</a>
            </li>
            <li className={`nav-item ${location.pathname === '/balance/' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
              <a className="nav-link" href="#/balance/" title="View balance" >Balance</a>
            </li>
            <li className={`nav-item ${location.pathname === '/alldata/' ? 'active' : ''}`}>
              <a className="nav-link" href="#/alldata/" title="View all data" >All Data</a>
            </li>
            <li className={`nav-item ${location.pathname === '/login/' ? '-active' : ''}`}>
              <a className="nav-link" href="#/login/" title="Login here" >Login</a>
            </li>          
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      ${console.log(location.pathname)}
    </>
  );

}
```

my styles

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #F39428;
   }

.navbar-nav .nav-link{
    color:azure;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item-active .nav-link
{
    color: blue !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 800;
    color:azure;

}
```

I'm not exacttly sure what I could be doing wrong here, please try to help me as I have been stuck on this for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `li` tag class to `active` but in `CSS` you are selecting `nav-item-active`.

Change `nav-item-active` to `active` In `CSS` and it will be OK.

Your classes are like this when its active:

```
"nav-item active"
```

And not:

```
"Nav-item-active"
```

(Also your login class is `-active`).